# Will reducing voltage to LED light strips from 8V to 5V cause the LED strip to fail faster?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, led-strip

I purchased some LED lights for my building facade and due to authority compliance, I have to reduce the voltage from 8V to 5V per meter. Thus modification was done and it seems that the LED strips are burning off at the supply end quite frequently.

1. What is the likely cause of this issue, and
2. How can I resolve it.

Comment: It would help if you include a picture of the strip, as well as a link to where you bought it from.

Comment: LEDs don't use a "volts per meter".  I've never heard of an authority dictating such a thing unless you had a series string and your string voltage exceeded legal limits for your wiring method.  Do you mean amps per meter? Maybe better to link the product so we can see what youhave .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably fail completely as there would not be enough voltage for the LEDs to light. However that is not going to damage the LEDs or cause them to fail prematurely. The fix: bring the voltage back up to rating and it will work fine.

Controlling brightness with LEDs does not work with voltage, it is in a very narrow range maybe 2V at most as they are current devices. If you use a PWM controller they will work great. Try this link for an an inexpensive unit, I use them and they work very well. https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256803840030102.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.4a3138dawfP0YR&mp=1&gatewayAdapt=glo2usa&_randl_shipto=US